# Abaqus DISP Subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

Currently I'm writing a subroutine `DISP` in `fortran`, I'm new to this. In this code I want to read a file for which I use

```
OPEN(UNIT = 1, FILE = "abcd.txt", FORM = "FORMATTED", STATUS = "OLD", ACTION = "READ")
```

These files contains values in a nxm Matrix. I want to assign the values in this matrix like for example `column 5 = displacement`, and `column 1 = nodes`.

Can I declare an array like `REAL,DIMENSION(n,m)::A` and then with `DO LOOP` assign values to `NODES` and `U(1)` which are already the parameters declared in the subroutine?

```
SUBROUTINE DISP(U,KSTEP,KINC,TIME,NODE,NOEL,JDOF,COORDS)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to be more readable. Please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on how to format a post. Also please ensure that I haven't made any mistakes in my edits that might invalidate code.

Comment: Now that I can read your question I can't understand it, I don't think you've provided enough code to properly illustrate what you are trying to do, what you have so far, and where you are stuck.  A sample of the input file might help too.  Unfortunately the answer to almost all the programming questions on SO which begin *Can I ...* is either *Yes, you can.* or *No, you can't*.  Neither is much use to you.  You probably ought to be asking *How can I ...* and then be very explicit about the trouble you're having answering that question for yourself.

Comment: you *must not* change any arguments except those listed under "Variable to be defined" in the documents, which in this case is only `U`.  You can do what you want with your own `A` you declare.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I declare an array like REAL,DIMENSION(n,m)::A and then with DO
>   LOOP assign values to NODES and U(1) which are already the parameters
>   declared in the subroutine?

No you can't assign to node in this way. The way DISP works is that it is called many times, once per degree of freedom. So for a given pass through DISP you will have to update the displacement for the node that Abaqus specifies in NODE and the direction specified in JDOF.

opening a file each time will be slow, so this may not be the best way to do it. The best solution would be to have your algorithm for working out U inside your DISP routine. 
A different solution would be to define your A matrix in the code. This would be a bit ugly in your code, but better than opening a file every time.